# JSON POST Request with Alamofire and EVReflection

Tags: ios, json, swift

I"m trying to do a simple POST request in swift. I'd like to post an array of objects (alarms) and I"m constantly running into problems. Here is what I have so far:

```
func submitAlarms(alarms: [Alarm],onCompletion: @escaping ([Alarm]) -> Void){

    let route = baseURL

    let token = SessionManager().storedSession!.token.idToken

    let headers = [
        "Authorization": "Bearer \(token)"
    ]


    let parameters = [
        "alarms": alarms.toJsonString()]

    print("Parameters ", parameters)


    Alamofire.request(route, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON{ response in

            switch response.result{
            case .failure(let error):
                print("POST Alarm JSON Error: \(error)")
            case .success(let value):
                let json = JSON(value)

                let alarms_json = json["alarms"]

                print(alarms_json)

                let alarms_string = alarms_json.rawString()

                let alarms: [Alarm] = [Alarm](json: alarms_string)

                //let alarms = [Alarm](json: res_string)

                onCompletion(alarms)

            }

    }

}
```

I"m mainly having issues with the `parameters` part. For whatever reason, Alamofire can't seem to take an array of objects, so I created a dictionary with a top level `alarm` key that holds the array of alarms. I then use EVReflection to convert my alarm array to a json string. But that conversion gives me this:

```
Parameters  ["alarms": "[\n{\n  \"isActive\" : true,\n  \"volume\" : 10,\n  \"minute\" : 15,\n  \"days\" : [\n    0,\n    1,\n    2,\n    3,\n    4,\n    5,\n    6\n  ],\n  \"brightness\" : 10,\n  \"hour\" : 6,\n  \"audio\" : 4,\n  \"duration\" : 1,\n  \"label\" : \"Alarm\",\n  \"allowSnooze\" : false,\n  \"isSynchronized\" : false\n}\n]"]
```

Where are all these extra `\` and `\n` coming from? Using Alamofire, the server responds with a 400 because these extra pieces make it invalid JSON. What am I missing here? I am using Xcode 8/Swift 3, with the latest Alamofire and EVReflection. I"ve looked at other examples, but they are mostly out of date. A lot of them also use extensions and custom encoding, which seems ridiculous for such a simple request. Appreciate any help and bonus points if you can clean up the response as well.

Answer (score 0):

For creating the parameters you are doing a:

```
let parameters = ["alarms": alarms.toJsonString()]
```

Which means that you will get 1 paramater that will contain the json as a string.
EVReflection will first convert the alarms object to a dictionary and then convert it to json using the Apple standard function:

```
JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, options: .prettyPrinted)
```

Since it's using the .prettyPrinted option it will be formatted in a nice readable format. This means that it will add /n for where there should be enters plus spaces for making a nice layout.

In your case you have to look at the api that you are calling to see what you should change in your code. Currently you are doing a http get. Then the parameters should be simple key - value pairs. You could use the EVReflection toDictionary function for that if you want to post all your object properties. But in your case I think you need to do a post (see Alamofire documentation) and then you can put the json in the request body.

P.S. I just found this issue by accident. You are welcome to also create issues at https://github.com/evermeer/EVReflection or ask questions at https://gitter.im/evermeer/EVReflection Then i will receive a notification for it.

Comment: Yes, I agree that my problem is that I"m creating a dictionary with one item and a single string of json, whereas what I really want is a complete dictionary including an array of the alarm objects. From there I believe that Alamofire will properly encode that into json. The toDictionary gave me some really weird results, but i haven't spent much time with it. BTW, I"m already doing a POST request, see above. I'll check out the link, thanks

Comment: then make sure that you don't add the dictionary to that other dictionary. Just do a .toDictionary() and put that in the parameters.